# Blocked for Internal Promotions. How do I get around the excuses?

Tags: work-environment, united-states, promotion

I feel like my company is dragging their feet because of *reasons*. It's always something new.  This is both within my department and to other departments.  My bosses have acknowledged that they know I won't be in the department long but just getting a promotion to the next level which I'm definitely qualified to be at is like pulling teeth. I already take on the additional responsibilities, so I want the pay bump to match.  Also, I've had talks with other department heads and they have spoken with my manager too, about me joining their teams and how they really are impressed with my work.  But the excuse is that they don't have the job open yet, blah blah blah.

I'm not very forward about this stuff, so should I be more forward? Btw if it's relevant, I've been at this company for more than 2.5 years and the company has more than 10k employees.

Comment: Hi. I edited your question to be more on-topic and fit for this site. Polls about how things work at other peoples companies are frowned upon here. However, you have a legitimate question that I think can be addressed. If my edit does not do your question justice you may roll it back.

Comment: @TheGirlHasNoName no problem. that is a good  edit.  I'm mostly on stack overflow so I wasn't aware of what you mentioned.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment about "They don't have the job open yet" it seems like your company has a HR or Head Count policy that will prevent managers from hiring anyone they want without further approval from up above. So each manager has a team and a limited head count and once its full, they either need to convince upper management to increase this quota or make do with loaning you off your current team for short periods of time.

Despite the above situation, when looking for a promotion, you should be trying to get clearly defined goals from your manager. This will allow you to have a better reason to be promoted as you can show that you what you have achieved and/or exceeded these goals. Its even better if your manager can make a guarantee in writing.

Unfortunately, if they stick to their policy, the only option might be to leave.

Comment: I guess this is what I was afraid of.  I've had friends at larger companies where it seems like a cakewalk for them to advance in the company. It's just ironic because every other month we hear about a new "initiative" to promote within and retain quality people.

Comment: @ZacharyGilliom I've had a colleague who was stuck in this situation and even had his manager pushing for him to get promoted. Unfortunately, your fight isn't with your management. Its with upper management  (so you and your manager are often on the same team). Upper management refused to budge and he left, but that isn't always the case.

Comment: well that's dissappointing because  that sounds just like my manager....

Comment: @ZacharyGilliom You should still follow up on the development goals required for you to get a promotion (or at least a salary increase). However your company might have a fixed Promotion structure where people can only get promoted after X amount of years. Alternatively you might be able to get your manager to help you find a legitimate job opening within the company.

Comment: so it's actually been about 7 months since I was told I'd be getting this interdepartment promotion to the next level.  when this was talked about I asked what the requirements were and basically the only requirement was that I would train people now.  Mind you I had trained someone else 6 months prior. Pretty unfortunate thing happened.  I actually developed a pretty good relationship with "upper management" while working on a project with another team.  Unfortunately "upper management" has shifted a bit and now my boss has to rehash the conversation with the new management